# NestJS include WWW-Authenticate header in jwt strategy

Tags: jwt, header, nestjs

I have a working nestjs passport JWT strategy, it returns a 401 unauthorized with invalid or missing bearer token, however, it does not set the response header WWW-Authenticate header, which I need to do for a client library that is expecting that in the header

In my AuthModule I register as so:

```
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: jwtConstants.secret,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '1m' }
    })
```

I've also estended the JWT-strategy as follows:

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: jwtConstants.secret,
    });
  }

  validate(payload: {
    sub: string;
    email: string;
  }): { userId: string; email: string } {
    return {
      userId: payload.sub,
      email: payload.email
    };
  }
}
```

How can I set WWW-Authenticate header, only in the case the strategy fails / returns 401?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it with a slightly different approach, you can use Exception Filters to intercept auth failures, this worked for me, perhaps someone will find it of use:

```
@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor() {}

  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const status = exception.getStatus();

    if (status === 401) {
      response.setHeader(
        'WWW-Authenticate',
        'Basic realm="Access to site", charset="UTF-8"',
      );
    }
    response.status(status).json(exception.getResponse());
  }
}
```

Then I can implement it globally in my main.ts as follows:

```
app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());
```

Answer (score 2):

By the [NestJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/passport#extending-guards), it's possible to extends the passport guards to achieve this result.

```
export class JwtGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    return super.canActivate(context);
  }

  handleRequest<TUser = any>(
    err: any,
    user: any,
    info: any,
    context: ExecutionContext,
    status?: any,
  ): TUser {
    if (err || !user) {
      const ctx = context.switchToHttp();
      const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();

      // Headers, cookies and more can be set here
      response.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="example.com');

      throw new UnauthorizedException(err);
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

One drawback could be that you might end up writing similar logic for all of your passport strategies, not worth of it your WWW-Authenticate header is always the same.

Comment: Is it possible to elaborate what my options are if my `www-authenticate` header is always same? Currently this answer appears the only way forward irrespective of whether `www-authenticate` header is same or not.